# Thumbnail in Geonetwork not visible

Tags: geonetwork, thumbnail

I try to import a thumbnail for my layers, but it does not work. I have the impression that the path is wrong.

When I click on the eye to preview my imported image (cf capture), it opens a "http://localhost:8080/geonetwork/srv/api/records/97471278-b3fa-486e-bc84-ae49e51289ec/attachments/limites_regionales_thumb.jpg" url.
Except that my Geonetwork is running on a url that is not in localhost, nor on port 8080, but "http://monurlperso:8280/geonetwork/srv/fre/catalog.search#/home"!

If I try "http://monurlperso:8280/geonetwork/srv/api/records/97471278-b3fa-486e-bc84-ae49e51289ec/attachments/limites_regionales_thumb.jpg" I can see my image.

How to correct this, by modifying a function in one of the installation files?

[image: cf capture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the right hostname, port and protocol in the system settings. Go to the *Admin console* -> *Settings* -> *Catalog server* section and set the *Host*, *Preferred Protocol* and *Port* options.
[image]

After that you can click on the *Update metadata records* to update existing records with the new URL. Check the [documentation](https://www.geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/4.0.x/en/administrator-guide/configuring-the-catalog/system-configuration.html#catalog-server) for further info.

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem of miniatures.
However I realize that I have the same problem for the automatic link generated with the resource ID. And yet the ID is the same as the one of the thumbnail that is displayed. 
- http://monurlperso:8280/geonetwork/srv/resourcesd1a6d525-0789-4dce-a892-aabf0f131b25 => KO
- http://monurlperso:8280/geonetwork/srv/api/records/d1a6d525-0789-4dce-a892-aabf0f131b25/attachments/limites_regionales_thumb.jpg?approved=true => OK
It could also be due to a bad parameter in the server section?

Comment: It seems like a missing `/` somewhere...

Comment: yes I said the same thing to myself, but if I try http://monurlperso:8280/geonetwork/srv/resources`/`d1a6d525-0789-4dce-a892-aabf0f131b25, I have this error : **{"error": { "message": "Service not found" , "class": "ServiceNotFoundEx" , "request": {} } }** !...